# Wordpress/React project only showing 10 posts

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

I've created a React.js page that uses Wordpress REST API as backend, trying to get my Archive/Blog page to display all my posts. I've set the Wordpress settings to 30:

[image]

but still - only 10 posts is displayed:

[image]

here is my React project: https://github.com/fransbernhard/wordpressReactSassWebpack

here is my wordpress theme: 
https://github.com/fransbernhard/wordpress-theme

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add parameter `?per_page=30` in query.

[WordPress REST API Pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/)